# Error while passing values from web3 to solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, javascript

I have an HTML front-end that calls a function in a contract to create/deploy another contract. The function works standalone in remix. I get an error "Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function" but I send the right number of elements. The javascript code is:

```
var borrowerAddress = '0x...';
$("#makeLoanButton").click(function() {
    $("#loader").show();
    myOriginator.makeLoan($("#loanID").val(), borrowerAddress, $("#loanAmount").val(), (err, res) => {
        if (!err) {
           $("#loader").hide();
        }
   });
});
```

the solidity code is:

```
    function addLoan(address _newLoan) public {
        // Add loan to originator
        Loan myLoan = Loan(_newLoan);
        loans.push(myLoan) -1;
        originatorLoanBalance += myLoan.getBalance();

    } // function addLoan(address _newLoan) public {

function makeLoan(bytes16 _loanID, address _borrower, uint _loanBalance) payable public {
    // Create new loan
    Loan myLoan = new Loan(_loanID, _borrower, address(this), _loanBalance);

    // Add loan to loans
    loans.push(myLoan) -1;

    // Now add new loan to array
    addLoan(address(myLoan));

    // Send loan balance to borrower
    if (!_borrower.send(_loanBalance)) {
        revert();
    }

} // function makeLoan(bytes16 _loanID, address _borrower, uint _loanBalance)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try to set the transaction object, since your function is `payable`

```
myOriginator.makeLoan($("#loanID").val(), borrowerAddress, $("#loanAmount").val(), {value: 1, gas: 2000}, (err, res) => {
        if (!err) {
           $("#loader").hide();
        }
   });
```

**note**: you can actually remove `_loanBalance` and use `msg.value` since your function is payable

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured the problem out. It was not a problem with my syntax but rather that I was referring to the wrong HTML ID! It should have been $(#loanBalance") instead of $(#loanAmount")!